# Create a folder inside the .app file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to create a folder for some images, I'm doing it right now using "New Group", inside the Project Navigator of my Xcode Project.

The problem comes when I see the contents of the `.app` package, and inside it the images are with all the other files (not inside my folder)

How can I create a folder that will be inside of the `.app`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Create a folder with the images.

**2.** While adding into the Xcode you drag and drop the folder and choose the option "Create folder references for any added folders".

The folder will be in **blue** color, not yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in you project folder, add image to that folder and then add them to Xcode.

Comment: That creates the folder in the Project navigator but not in the .app

Comment: -1 for: this will not create a folder within the .app / ipa file!